# ngx-translate-core can't translate ng-container element

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

```
<ng-container [translate]="'name'">Names</ng-container>
```

ngx-translate can't translate it. But if I change this element to span, it's translated. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this: https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-ng-container-directive-in-angular-a97b7a33c8ea.

ng-container is a logical container used to wrap node,  its not render in the DOM. So it makes sense it wouldnt get translate.